# C# best way to share project but expose only methods required

Tags: c#, interface, shared-libraries

I have a Visual Studio Solution with two Web API projects and some shared or common projects.

- WebAPI_1 (Big API)
- WebAPI_2 (Very small API)
- Data Respository

  - SecurityRepository.cs
- Data Interface

  - ISecurityRepository.cs
- Services

  - SecurityService.cs
- Utility

`WebAPI_2` project will use some methods from `SecurityService.cs` but only 5 from almost 50.

`SecurityService.cs` inside calls the methods using `Dependency Injection` from `ISecurityRepository`

Because when referencing a project will expose the complete DLL, is there a way that WebAPI_2 only sees the 5 methods that is going to use but there is no way to see the other 45 methods?

Also because `Dependency Injection` is used I was thinking maybe on creating other Interface with only the methods that `WebAPI_2 SecurityService` is going to use. But again the problem is that the whole Data.Interface project will be referenced.

I don't want to end having 2 projects of each just because of this.

**Update**: Don't know if `InternalsVisibleTo` could be used in this scenario but at the method level.

Comment: Access modifiers seem like they're made for this kind of thing unless I'm misreading the situation here.

Comment: All the methods are public. But I would like to protect some of them from being used by WebAPI_2, but WebAPI_1 can access them

Comment: Not the best way to do it, but you could create another `SecurityService` that has all the methods, but throws a security exception when you try to call the irrelevant methods. How you distinguish which one to use though is a different problem... What is the issue with having the other methods? They just aren't relevant? Or they are security holes?

Comment: Security holes actually, and because WebAPI_2 is going to be in hand of people that we cant "trust" 100%, thats why. But we dont want to end creating duplicate projects with their own methods, etc. Because at the end any change that is done to this common projects has to be published for WebAPI_1 and 2

Comment: @VAAA "WebAPI_2 is going to be in hand of people that we cant "trust" 100%" - in the sense that they might be nefarious, or not trusted to not make mistakes?

Comment: Not trusted to not make mistakes and end seeing other methods and trying to call something that could make a big problem.

Comment: I think the problem is not about modifiers or access limitations. Decomposing the project to smaller modules should be done based on functionalities of them, not the technical issues. Are you sure the Services library is single responsible?

Comment: Have you considered using the [`PrincipalPermissionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-restrict-access-with-the-principalpermissionattribute-class) on your methods? Is that something that you could use?

Comment: Either add _authorization_ to your services or roll them up into a single aggregator like Azure API Management

Answer (score 0):

If you have source code for each of the API's, group them into a single assembly, marking everything as internal, and create a public API to expose it to external consumers.

I recommend using a Dot Net Obfuscation tool.  C# sources are too easy to reverse engineer.  If theft is an issue, program in C or C++ and expose a managed wrapper to C#.  Beyond that, use a hardware encryption device to run/decrypt the program on the fly.